# Different results with focus mode FOCUS_MODE_MACRO on different devices

Tags: android

It all comes down to differences between devices. I want to seto focus of the camera to very close as I want to capture images of objects very close to the camera I have tested this on device Samsung Galaxy S2 and LG G2.

So, to make it short I do the following:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
```

Now, if I just leave at that on device Samsung Galaxy S2 and do not call autoFocus() this produces very good result. Image is stable and focused on near objects, just what I want.
But if I run this same code on LG G2 the image is focused further away and to far ti be of any use. I have to run autoFocus() repeatedly and while it manages to acquire focus it not as practical as on SGS2 without autofocus() calls. Sometime auto focus gets distracted by something further away or the lightning conditions are not favorable.
My guess is that by setting focus mode to FOCUS_MODE_MACRO the camera focus is put to some arbitrary position. It is perhaps just coincidence that on SGS2 is near (OK) and on LG G2 the arbitrary position is away (not OK). 
Is there a way to force the focus to its minimum value, or is autoFocus() the only way with mixed results? Can anybody with experience provide some tips?